# iOS UIWebView loadHTMLString does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, webview

I try:

```
let body = "<body>.. ANYTHING ..</body>"
self.webView.loadHTMLString(body, baseURL: NSURL(string: "www.google.com")!)
```

or

```
self.webView.loadHTMLString(body, baseURL: nil)
```

If I print:

```
 self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.outerHTML")!
```

This print:

```
<body></body>
```

That is not my entire html..

Any ideas?

## notice

body is get from

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
                            if error == nil {
    let body = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

and yes, is not empty

Answer (score 2):

if you call

```
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.outerHTML")!
```

right after calling `loadHTMLString` is desired behavior because UIWebView loads content asynchronously. Set up `UIWebView`'s delegate in `viewDidLoad` and then in delegate method call this evaluateJS...

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) 
{
    let body = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.outerHTML")!
    println(body)
}
```

Comment: as far as I know - nope. To evaluate this JS String on loaded content you have to make sure, that it's loaded - and only way to make sure that it is loaded it's inside this delegate method

Comment: Thanks, I solved in this way (is the solution that i wanted to avoid btw)

Answer (score 0):

save your html file into your project and then load the html in webview, please see below , if this doesnt help please check this :- [link](http://makeapppie.com/2014/10/28/swift-swift-using-uiwebviews-in-swift/)

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "html");
        let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
        webView.loadRequest(myRequest);
        //or use as below 
        let myHTMLString:String! = "<h1>Hello Pizza!</h1>"
        webView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```